# Webpack aliases: what is the difference between "./{path}" and "{path}"?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have some React components defined in `app/components/`. I've setup some aliases in webpack like this:

```
//webpack.conf.js
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        alias: {
            Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
            Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx',
            Weather: 'app/components/Weather.jsx',
            About: 'app/components/About.jsx'
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My question is: why do all the aliases start with `'app'` and not `'./app'`? When I change the alias to starting with `'./'` (because I thought they were equivalent), webpack complains that `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve...`, so it seems they are not equivalent.

Why for `entry` and `output.filename`, they do require `'./'`? Is it because `resolve.root: __dirname`? What is the purpose of `__dirname` (both in `resolve and in`output`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dirname` points to the current directory that your `webpack.config.js` resides in. Thus when you specify the location of the output file with `path: __dirname`, the output file's location will be relative to the main directory in which your `webpack.config.js` resides.

Regarding the use of `./` in resolve: the path resolves relative to the file containing the `require` call. Because of that, you should use absolute paths in your webpack.config.js to avoid the need to think about relative paths when calling aliased files/modules. See the webpack documentation [**here**](http://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html).

> The relative path is joined to the context directory and the resulting
>   absolute file is resolved according to “Resolving an absolute path”.

Thus you need not use `./` while working with alias. 
You can see examples of which aliases will be resolved to what [**here**](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)
I hope I was able to explain it.

Comment: This [link](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) was great. Thanks

Comment: Happy to Help! :). Kindly accept the answer if you found it useful.